# How to get distinct values from List<Dictionay<string, string>> in c#

Tags: c#

Due to limitations on the system I am getting data from, I end up with duplicate Dictionaries in a orders list. The system looks at the amount of items and gives me one order for each item inside the order. Basically I end up with this:

```
            List<Dictionary<string, string>> myOrders = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

            Dictionary<string, string> dictionay = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            dictionay.Add("OrderId", "00000082");
            dictionay.Add("Order Status", "In Process");
            myOrders.Add(dictionay);
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionay1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dictionay1.Add("OrderId", "00000082");
            dictionay1.Add("Order Status", "In Process");
            myOrders.Add(dictionay1);
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionay2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dictionay2.Add("OrderId", "00000083");
            dictionay2.Add("Order Status", "In Process");
            myOrders.Add(dictionay2);
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionay3 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dictionay3.Add("OrderId", "00000084");
            dictionay3.Add("Order Status", "In Process");
            myOrders.Add(dictionay3);
```

I am sure there is a simple way to do this but I am having a hard time to loop through the myOrders and compare the OrderId value in order to end up with distinct dictionaries within the list. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you want as output, exactly?  It's not entirely clear what you want to end up with after filtering this data...

Comment: You are right, I did not specify what I need as output. Based on the example, I need a list that has only one entry for OrderId 00000082.

Comment: Don't torture yourself: use a proper data structure, not a `Dictionary` for this. `OrderId` and `OrderStatus` properties on an `Order` class would be in order (pun intended). If this means translating the dictionaries first, do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest first selecting out the distinct IDs:

```
IEnumerable<string> ids = myOrders.Select(order => order["OrderId"]).Distinct();
```

Then selecting the first dictionary corresponding to each id:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> distinctOrders = 
    ids.Select(id => 
        myOrders.First(order => order["OrderId"] == id)).ToList();
```

I'd also suggest you shouldn't use Dictionaries for this purpose and should instead create an `Order` class with `OrderId` and `OrderStatus` as properties on that class.

Alternatively, if you don't mind adding a third-party dependency, you might consider [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), which has a `DistinctBy` method suitable for this. If you use that, you'd simply do:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> distinctOrders = 
    myOrders.DistinctBy(order => order["OrderId"]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

First off - If each list item is a single entry, you might want to consider switching to `List<Tuple<string,string>>` or `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`.

That being said, you could get a unique list of `OrderId` values via something like:

```
var uniqueIds = new HashSet<string>(
                     myOrders
                     .SelectMany(o => o) // Extract all KeyValuePairs
                     .Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "OrderId")
                     .Select(kvp => kvp.Value));
```

Comment: How would this work? It'd select out all the order statuses as well as the Ids.

Comment: @BenAaronson Yeah - realized that after posting - and fixed.